# jQuery toggleClass/removeClass/addClass with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

I'm trying to use jQuery which is always a nightmare for me.

I have 4 different dropdowns that have a class added when an element is clicked.
I'm trying to use jQuery to check if any of the dropdowns have the open class, if so, then remove it and delay adding the open class to whichever other element is click.

```
<div class="parent-container">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/263x263" alt="#" class="img-responsive">
                    <hr>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-lg xbox-toggle"></i>
                </div>
                <ul class="xbox-container">
                    <li class="price-single">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="#">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>£39.99</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="price-single">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="#">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>£39.99</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="price-single">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="#">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>£39.99</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end col -->

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="parent-container">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/263x263" alt="#" class="img-responsive">
                    <hr>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-lg playstation-toggle"></i>
                </div>
                <ul class="playstation-container">
                    <li class="price-single">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="#">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>£39.99</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="price-single">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="#">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>£39.99</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="price-single">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" alt="#">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>£39.99</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end col -->

$('.xbox-toggle').click(function() {
  $('ul.xbox-container').toggleClass('price-cont-open');
  if($('ul.playstation-container').hasClass('price-cont-open')){
    $('ul.playstation-container').removeClass('price-cont-open');
    $('ul.xbox-container').addClass('price-cont-open').delay(1000);
  };
});
```

Comment: Show us your html and what does this means `and delay adding the open class to whichever other element is click.`???

Comment: Have you heard of `setTimeout`? It's THE basic "delay something" thing.

Comment: If one of the dropdown menu's is open and another one is clicked to be opened, I want to remove the price-cont-open from the dropdown which is already opened, and add it to the one that has been clicked, but with a delay so the dropdowns don't overlap

Comment: any css would be nice here..

Comment: You've basically got two options then as far as I'm concerned. Use `setTimeout` to add the class after a delay, or add a CSS transition (only compatible with newer browsers) to set a duration for how long it takes to display the drop-down.

Comment: Why do you need the CSS? The animation is fine, it's the exchange between adding and removing classes that I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example that uses `jQuery.Deferred()` a jQuery like implementation of the Promise ES6 spec.

so, hope it helps: have a look on the `self.sleep` method and how it works in combination with a promise chain...

```js
function ExampleCtrl($) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.ACTIVE_CLASS = 'active';
  self.list = $('.example');
  self.items = $('> li', self.list);
  self.sleep = function(ms) {
    ms = ms || 1000;
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve();
    }, ms);
    
    return deferred.promise();
  };  

  self.items.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var current = $(this);
    
    return $
      .when(current.toggleClass(self.ACTIVE_CLASS))
      .then(function() {
        return self.sleep(3000);
      })
      .then(function() {
        return current.next();
      })
      .then(function(sibling) {
        return sibling.toggleClass(self.ACTIVE_CLASS);
      })
    ;
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(ExampleCtrl);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 150ms all linear;
  background: lightcoral;
  margin: 2px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="example">
  <li class="active">Item 1</li>
  <li class="">Item 2</li>
  <li class="">Item 3</li>
  <li class="">Item 4</li>
  <li class="">Item 5</li>
  <li class="">Item 6</li>
  <li class="">Item 7</li>
  <li class="">Item 8</li>
  <li class="">Item 9</li>
</ul>
```